# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

here is my script :

```
<script>
var count;
var obj;

function recherche() {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "test.json", true);
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var res = xhr.responseText;
            obj = JSON.parse(res);

            for (count = 0; count < obj.length; count++) {
                alert(obj[count].humidity);
            }
        }

    }

}
                            alert(obj);

window.onload = recherche;
</script>
```

I have this error after running this script:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

the first alert works fine showing me 20,30,40 but if i do the alert outside i have undefined.

I would like to use the object obj to use its data stored from json file as data to draw charts furthermore in the script.but this error pops out.

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, XHR requests are *asynchronous*. That means that `send` *starts* them, but they complete later (which is why they have callbacks rather than return values). Just use `obj` within the callback.

---

Side note: Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (you never declare your `xhr` variable).

Comment: but i need the obj later in another function :/

Comment: @YoussefKamoun: Then you call that function from the callback.